# JAVA: Why do I keep getting these runtime errors?

Tags: java, debugging, methods, runtime-error

Wrote a roshambo program, ran it once, worked fine, ran it again and the following errors popped up:

RoShamBo!

1. Play Game
2. Show Score
3. Quit

1

Which do you choose?

1. Rock
2. Paper
3. Scissors

2

Which do you choose?

1. Rock
2. Paper
3. Scissors

Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)

at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)

at RoShamBo.getUserChoice(RoShamBo.java:82)

at RoShamBo.winner(RoShamBo.java:112)


at RoShamBo.main(RoShamBo.java:27)
```

not sure on how to deal with these type of errors, this my first time using methods so i'm thinking it has to do with how I called each method? please help.

thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RoShamBo 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("RoShamBo!");
    System.out.println("1. Play Game");
    System.out.println("2. Show Score");
    System.out.println("3. Quit");
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    if(userInput.hasNextInt())
    {
        int userIn = userInput.nextInt();
        if(userIn == 1)
        {
            getUserChoice();
            getCompChoice();
            winner();
        }
        else if(userIn == 2)
        {
            scores();
        }
        else if(userIn == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Qutiing: Final Score was: ");
            scores();
            userInput.close();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.");
            userInput.next();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.");
        userInput.next();
    }
}      
public static String getUserChoice()
{
    // ask player for a move : playerMove
    System.out.println("Which do you choose?");
    System.out.println("1. Rock");
    System.out.println("2. Paper");
    System.out.println("3. Scissors");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userChoice = " ";

    if (input.hasNextInt())
    {
        int userInput = input.nextInt();
        switch(userInput)
        {
            case 1:
                    userChoice = "Rock";
                    break;
            case 2:
                    userChoice = "Paper";
                    break;
            case 3:
                    userChoice = "Scissors";
                    break;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.");
        input.next();
    }
    input.close();
    return userChoice;
}
private static String getCompChoice()
{
    //Method for getting Computers move
    int compChoice = (int) ( 1 + (Math.random() * 3));
    String compMove = " ";
    switch(compChoice)
    {
        case 1:
                compMove = "Rock";
                break;
        case 2:
                compMove = "Paper";
                break;
        case 3:
                compMove = "Scissors";
                break;
    }

    return compMove;
}

public static String winner()
{
    String winnerIs = " ";
    String comp = getCompChoice();
    String user = getUserChoice();
    if(user.equals("Rock") && comp.equals("Scissors") ||
       user.equals("Paper") && comp.equals("Rock") ||
       user.equals("Scissors") && comp.equals("Paper"))
    {          
        System.out.println("You Win!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You Lose");
    }
    return winnerIs;
}
public static void scores()
{
    int compCount = 0;
    int userCount = 0;
    if (winner().equals("You Win!"))
    {
        userCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        compCount++;
    }
    System.out.println("Player = " + userCount );
    System.out.println("Computer = " + compCount );
}
}
```

Comment: You are familiar with concept of loop, right? From what I see, there should be at least one somewhere, if you want user input to be read more than once.

Comment: When user wants to play, you call `getUserChoice();` and `getCompChoice();` without storing the result and then in `winner()` you call them once again, user has to play twice!

Comment: As @Jens said, it is difficult to troubleshoot your problem without knowing _how_ you caused the problem. If you just want to handle the exception, you can use try and catch statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably here

```
 {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry, Please Try Again.");
        input.next();
    }
```

you are doing a `next()` without checking for `has*()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your stack gives one hint.

```
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source).
```

and

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

Turning to the documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29

part that is of interest to you:

> Throws:
>       NoSuchElementException - if no more tokens are available

You call `.next()`
but what do you want to read? Is there anything waiting in input buffer? Also, see my comment, meaning that your logic is busted.**Rethink** your game logic instead of fixing it.

Giving a complete answer that gets your code to run like it's supposed to would mean writing most of your code, I won't go that way. Instead, you should apply one of the most powerful debugging methods known to humans and do it yourself:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Good luck and enjoy ;)